Alarm stops all media sound, Antix Linux Chromebook
after a few minutes media playing is interrupted by a loud alarm. i used alsamixer, played with the card, which toggles off, used WeirdTreeThing, (which states it may not work on this distro) disabled pipewire, enabled pulse audio. expertise would be appreciated.
thank you

maybe the alarm sound is embedded in the media file

I resolved the issue by reinstalling WeirdTreeThing
and editing the audio session sleep time to 10.
